# Rails Generator: generate files based on already existing rails files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I wanted to make a generator that created files (and directories, etc...) based on already existing files in the app (for instance, the views or controllers). So if we had views set up like this

```
-app
   -views 
        - layouts
             - application.html.erb
        - users
             - index.html.erb
             - show.html.erb 
             - etc ...
```

and I wanted to create files based on them I can do (with just ruby)

```
directories = Dir.entries("#{Rails.root}/app/views")
directories.each do |directory|
  unless directory == "." or directory == ".."
    files = Dir.entries("#{Rails.root}/app/views/#{directory}")
    files.each do |file|
      unless file == "." or file == ".."
        text = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/views/#{directory}/#{file}")      
        something #=> whatever else needs to go here to edit the file
        something else #=> output_file.puts whatever
      end
    end
  end
end
```

so this is basically what I would like to do with a generator so I can roll my code into a plugin and use it for other apps.

First question,  **how can I generate arbitrary files (with filenames based on existing filenames using the generator.** Is it appropriate to cycle through the directories like I did above, grab the directory/file and generate files? Is there a way to do what I did using a simpler method (mine seems easily breakable).

Also, should I put all that read/format/write code  ***inside the generator itself***  and just pass a string into the `"initialize content"` section of `create_file` or should I put it somewhere else. Or should I use the generator to create the bare files and populate it with an init script?

Is there a more  *rails*  type of way of populating generated files, or should I just shove all my formatting code inside the generator. If so, what is the appropriate way to approach this.

Comment: Your question ends very abruptly "If so, what is the". Do you have more to add?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to know how generators are built in rails3 or not. The code you are showing is not very generator-like. In generators you can use all commands from [Thor](http://rdoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Actions.html), which offers you a very powerful toolset of manipulating files, and injecting code (strings) into classes or files.

So I would most definitely fill your files inside a generator, because then it happens on user request, and the user can choose whether or not certain files need or can be overwritten or not.

Inside your gem, you will have a `lib/generators` folder, containing a `templates` folder, containing all files you might want to place inside the rails application.

From the Thor documentation, here is [a nice example](https://github.com/wycats/thor/wiki/Generators) to construct files in a generator.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

there's a simple API to use generators in Rails. here you can find a good guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

if you want to check some code:

https://github.com/coderloop/tamed_beast (I'm the author of its generators)

https://github.com/pilu/web-app-theme (another clean example)

Comment: It was not me who down-voted your answer however I would suggest that it was down-voted because it is 3 links to other sites with no real content of its own. With the sometimes transient nature of external links then this answer could end up as just a set of dead links.

Comment: @Steve: thank you for your explanation. it's not my habit to blinldy paste links. in this case, considering that the solution is not so *easy* to fit in a complete answer, I pasted a complete guide with some real (and simple) examples to show how to work with rails generators. I'm the author of tamed_beast's generators, so I can provide more help if needed.

Comment: I agree with Steve it was probably about just posting links, but I have read through them and they are slightly helpful, but I was really looking for an explanation not just code.